# Show that sigma algebra is coarser than other sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and the measure space $(S,\mathcal S)$. $I\neq \emptyset$.  Let $X=(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be $\mathcal F-\mathcal S$ measurable random variables with values in $S$.

Let \begin{equation}\mathcal E:=\Big\{\{X_{i_1}\in A_1,\dots,X_{i_n}\in A_n\}\Big|n \in \mathbb N, i_1,\dots,i_n \in I, A_1,\dots,A_n \in \mathcal S\Big\}\end{equation}
What is the argument for
$$\mathcal E\subseteq \sigma(X_i:i \in I)$$

or does this follow from definition, i.e. $\sigma(X_i:i \in I)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X_i, i \in I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_{i_1},X_{i_2},...,X_{i_n}$ are all measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X_i: i \in I)$ and hence $X_{i_1}^{-1}(A_1) \cap X_{i_2}^{-1}(A_2)... \cap X_{i_n}^{-1}(A_n) $ belongs to $\sigma (X_i: i \in I)$.

Comment: @Surb No. Why would a countable intersection of sets of the type $X_i^{-1}(A)$ belong to $\mathcal E$?

Comment: Indeed, I thought that $\mathcal E$ was a $\sigma -$algebra (the title confused me).